# C++ reinitializing variables in a while loop

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a settings menu that can make the window fullscreen. Most of the menu elements are dependent on the window size. By default, all the menu elements are in the same position they were in before the window was resized (meaning they are not in the position I intend). I understand the positions needs to be recalculated, but in this instance, rather than create a function that resets the position of all the elements in the menu, I've just called the initial `load()` function.

Here is a code summary to help:

```
     while(!exit) {
      switch(State) {
        case Menu:
        
          Menu settings = Menu(...);
          settings.load() //load here

          while(State == Menu) {
            
            if (window.fullscreen()) {
              settings.load(); //reload here
            }
            
          }//end while
        break;
        default:
        break;
      }//end switch
    }//end while
```

This works, but I'm worried about the memory used by `load()` when it was first called. The variables use the same name, but are new objects created? Are they overwritten? What happened to the memory that stored the objects when I first loaded the menu?

Also, the "What" that is being loaded and reloaded here is a `std::unique_ptr<Table>` that  makes a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<TextRect>>>`.

Edit: the `Settings` class:

```
class Settings {

  Window& _window;
  sf::RenderWindow& _win;
  //MainState& _mainState;
  MenuState& _menuState;
  Resources& _res;
  Input& _input;

  std::unique_ptr<TextRect> SettingsBanner;
  std::unique_ptr<Table> SettingsMenu;
  std::unique_ptr<Table> SettingsSave;

public:

  Settings(Window& pWindow
          ,MainState& pMainState
          ,MenuState& pMenuState
          ,Resources& pResources
          ,Input& pInput
          );
  ~Settings();

  void load();
  void update();

private:

  void inputs();

};
```

and the `load()`:

```
void Settings::load() {

  //all kinds of variables

  SettingsBanner = std::make_unique<TextRect>(_win
                                             ,string
                                             ,font
                                             ,texture
                                             ,sf::Color::White
                                             ,size
                                             ,origin
                                             ,position
                                             ,sf::Color::White
                                             ,outColor
                                             ,charSize
                                             ,outline
                                             );

  //more variables

  SettingsMenu = std::make_unique<Table>(_win
                                        ,font
                                        ,texture
                                        ,textureColor
                                        ,fillColor
                                        ,outColor
                                        ,charSize
                                        ,outline
                                      );

  SettingsMenu->element("FullScreen");
  SettingsMenu->element("VSync");
  SettingsMenu->element("FrameRate");
  SettingsMenu->element("Volume");

  SettingsMenu->makeTable("CenterLeft", position, rowCol);

  //more variables

  SettingsSave = std::make_unique<Table>(_win
                                        ,font
                                        ,texture
                                        ,textureColor
                                        ,fillColor
                                        ,outColor
                                        ,charSize
                                        ,outline
                                        );

  SettingsSave->element("Save");
  SettingsSave->element("Back");

  SettingsSave->makeTable("BottomRight", position, rowCol);

}// end func
```

Comment: Are you aware it should be `while(State == Menu)` instead of `while(State = Menu)`? :-)

Comment: it's a typo I made when I attempted to distill the code. it has nothing to do with my question, but I will correct it.

Comment: Yes, new objects are created. But why does this worry you? As long as your code has correct destructors (and copy constructors and assignment operators) then everything will be managed correctly.

Comment: In the case of this menu, It's only a handful of objects, but what if the window is resized when many objects are on the screen? Say the window is resized 100 times, and ```load()``` is called 100 times. Does there exist 100 copies of the same object?

Comment: As long as we don't know what `settings` is and what `load` does, we can't really help you. If you doing it right I don't see any problems, if you're doing it wrong there will be problems.

Comment: settings is a wrapper class for a ```std::unique_ptr<table>``` that contains a ```std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<TextRect>>>```. I thought the question did not require such an expansive example, but I will provide one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: `std::make_unique` makes new objects, every time it's called. It *cannot* reuse the memory of the previous object. What would happen if the constructor of the new object throws an exception? It's only in the assignment to the existing `unique_ptr` that the old object is discarded, and you wouldn't get there if an exception is thrown. This ensures *exception safety*.

You can of course write `Settings::load()` in different ways. If `SettingsBanner` is not empty, you can assign to `*SettingsBanner` instead of calling `std::make_unique`.

Comment: I don't know if I'm grasping 100% of what you've said, but I'm getting that once a ```unique_ptr``` is assigned to an object, it points to the object and "Holds" it, and if a call is made to remake the object, that original ```unique_ptr``` is still pointing to and "holding" the object. Is that about correct?

Comment: @dinky: If you look at the full statement `SettingsBanner = std::make_unique<TextRect>(...)`, there are four important function calls in order: to `std::make_unique`, to `new`, to `TextRect`'s constructor, and to `std::unique_ptr::operator=`. The old object is only released by the last call. That is because `std::unique_ptr<TextRect>`can hold only one object at a time, and it's a clean swap between the old and the new object.

Comment: I'm trying to understand.. When you say "the old object is only released by the last call," that last call is the ```std::unique_ptr::operator=```, which in this case is the ```SettingsBanner = std::...```, is that correct? So the last call is to equate everything after = to the ```SettingsBanner```, so if that last call is changed, as in ```SettingsBanner``` now equals something else, then the last call has released it's hold on the previous object, is that correct?

Comment: @dinky: Correct, calling `operator=` on `SettingsBanner` swaps out the old `TextRect` for the new one. And to be very very explicit, this will call the destructor of the old `TextRect`.

Comment: I'm sure I'll wonder why my old TextRect is being destroyed in the future, but for now this will do. Thank you so much for your help MSalters.